# IPersistable Interface - Any trick or hack to change field name

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, interface

For a class that can be saved in a persistence medium i am creating Interface called `IPersistable` which is designed to provide a `persistenceId`.

```
public interface IPersistable
{
    private readonly string persistenceId;
}
```

**Certainly i can't do** the above since Interfaces do not allow fields. If it did i would have done below to accomplish it

```
Public Class Customer
{

 private readonly string persistenceId;

 Public string UserId
   {
     get{return persistenceId};
   }

 Public Customer(string customerId)
  {
    persistenceId = customerId;
  }
}
```

I already am inheriting a class hence not possible to do multiple inheritance. I could use composition but Interface seems right thing here. Show me a neat hack to do the above instead of adding a property to each class that needs to be persisted.

#### Question

If possible, can a class that Interfaces with `IPersistable` change the name of the property( if persistenceId is a property), to something meaningful ?

Comment: Interfaces are public contracts for external use, why do those using this interface need to care what the private field is called?  You cannot change public member names, that would break the contract.

Comment: You seem to prefix this private field with the class name or something deduced from the class name. This is unnecessary; `Customer.id` seems like a better name than `Customer.customerId`, and also avoids you wanting to rename the property for each class (which isn't possible anyway). Also, are you aware that you can have properties in an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface won't help you if you want to be able to persist existing types such as int or string.  Maybe instead of an interface you could use a wrapping class?  Something like:

```
class Persistable<T>
{
    public Persistable<T>(string PersistanceId, T Data)

    public readonly string PersistanceId;
    public readonly T Data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with?

```
public interface IPersistable
{
    String PersistenceId { get; }
}

Public Class Customer : IPersistable
{

    public string PersistenceId { get; private set; }

    public string UserId { 
         get { return PersistenceId; } 
    }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: that would mean `Customer.UserId` and `Customer.PersistenceId` why would i want to have 2 id's that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public interface IPersistable<TType>
{
   TType PersistenceId { get; }
}

public abstract PersistableEntity<TType> : IPersistable<TType>
{
   private TType persistenceId;

   public TType PersistenceId
   {
       get { return persistenceId; }
   }

   public PersistableEntity(TType persistenceId)
   {
      this.persistenceId = persistenceId;
   }
}

public class Customer : PersistableEntity<string>
{
   public Customer(string persistenceId)
     : base(persistenceId)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: TIdentity would have been better ;)